Modify Appscript so that Execution Time will not be Exceeded
Help me please. I am trying to consolidate all data from different sheets located in folder id 16jQGy_NZJWazugBTfkv48s-egT48RsRI. However, there are too many data in every sheets, so execution time exceeded. Can you help me modify the script so that execution time will not be exceeded? I can't give the files since they are confidential. At least you can help me where to edit. Thank you!
function mergeDataFromSheets() {


  // Get the folder ID where the source spreadsheets are located
  const folderId = "16jQGy_NZJWazugBTfkv48s-egT48RsRI";

  // Get the active spreadsheet (the master spreadsheet)
  const masterSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    // Set the new spreadsheet ID where the "DTR_Merge" sheet is located
  const newSpreadsheet = masterSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("DTR_Merge");
  newSpreadsheet.clearContents();

  // Get the target cell value from the "Teacher Rate" sheet
  const targetCell = masterSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Teacher Rate").getRange("Q3").getValue();

  // Get the folder containing the source spreadsheets
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

  // Get all files in the folder with the specified MIME type (Google Sheets)
  const files = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

  // Iterate through each file
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());

    // Get the sheet with the specified name from the source spreadsheet
    const sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetCell);

    if (sourceSheet) {
      // Calculate the last row with data in the source sheet
      const lastRow = sourceSheet.getRange("C3:C").getValues().filter(String).length + 2;

      // Get the data range from the source sheet
      const dataRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A3:J" + lastRow);
      const dataValues = dataRange.getValues();

      // Append the data to the "DTR_Merge" sheet in the new spreadsheet
      newSpreadsheet.getRange(newSpreadsheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, dataValues.length, dataValues[0].length).setValues(dataValues);
    }
  }
}

I have a script in appscript that works well but execution time exceeded.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices has "exactly" what you are looking for.

Reduce the number of calls to Google Apps Scripts.
From
const file = files.next();
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());

To
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);

Instead of using multiple SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange use SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange().getValues() to get all the sheet values at once. Then use methods to handle array values to get the values that you need.

If have a lot of files stored on Google Drive, despite of your best efforts to having a neat script in terms of efficency, it might still exceeds the maximum execution time. If this is your case you must decide what workaround route you will want to take

Instead of putting all the files in a single folder, split the files across multiple folders and run the script on each folder.
Limit the number of files to handle on each execution. For this, one option is to store a token, the use it on the next execution. Reapeat until all the files get processed.
Elegantly exit before exceeding the execution time limit. On this option you might use a token or another method to avoid processing the same files again.




I might add links to related questions and /or examples later.

The only way is to break it into different functions within a script with each function handling only few sheets.
Through few hit and trial you can figure out how much each function can safely handle without timing out.
Now try to execute each function individually.
Thanks
